# delete data without navigating another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, delete-row

```
func deleteData(id:String){
   
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "User")
   fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = '\(id)'")
  
   do
   {
       let test = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
       
       let objectToDelete = test[0]
       context.delete(objectToDelete)
       
       do{
           try context.save()
       }
       catch(let error)
       {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
       
   }
   catch(let error)
   {
       print(error)
   }

}
```

This is delete function

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var array = [Dictionary<String,String>]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

var id = ""

var obj = Dictionary<String,String>()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableview.delegate = self
    self.tableview.dataSource = self
    
    array = DataHandler.sharedInstance.fetch()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let obj = array[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    
    cell.usernameLabel.text = obj["username"]
    cell.emailLabel.text = obj["email"]
    cell.passwordLabel.text = obj["password"]

    cell.updateBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapUpdateBtn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.updateBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    
    return cell
}

 @objc func didTapUpdateBtn(sender:UIButton)
{
    let obj = array[sender.tag]
    let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "update") as! UpdateViewController
    vc.obj = obj
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

This is tableview controller

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var idLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var updateBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

This is table view cell

I am performing crud operation with core data.I have performed 3 operation successful which is working fine but in delete operation we have no need to navigate another controller just click on button action will be performed.I am so confused how to do it i have tried so many method.

Comment: Yes i have heard

Comment: Confirm If I am right. Your didTapUpdateBtn() this button is navigating to next screen. But on tapping delete you dont want to navigate right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: So simply you can remove navigation code on delete button.

Comment: Is that working??

Comment: I have do it but delete record on Id base how to get id

Comment: Use this to get index of current deleting row  cell.deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row.

Comment: If you have id in model the use cell.deleteBtn.tag = obj["id"]

Comment: I have used this as like didtapupdatebtn but didn't solve my problem

Comment: After deleting row also use code self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic). This will remove row from tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
cell.deleteBtn.tag = obj["id"]
```

Where `obj = array[indexPath.row]`
So you will definitely get **id** for specific **row to delete**.

After deleting row also use code

`self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`.

This will remove row from tableview.
**OR**
Just **reload your TableView** by using below code.

```
self.dataDisplayTbleView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I am trying this will show cannot assign value of type 'String? ' to int

Comment: It is because your id is of String Type. Can you make your id as Integer type.

Comment: Just change the type of id in your Core data structure.

Comment: Tell me that what is type of id in your Core Data Structure?

Comment: In core data structure id is string and I want to use string I have changed but still same error

Comment: Now when I use self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic). In this code index path issue

Comment: Where I found indexpath.row

Comment: What are you passing in [indexPath]?

Comment: I am trying to pass indexpath.row  but I am not using table view function so I have no index path how to get index path. Row

Comment: Use this code :-  var indexPath = IndexPath(row: 12, section: 0). Pass integer Id in row. and your indexPath is ready to use.

Comment: I have used sender.tag it's working fine thanks

Comment: Welcome. Can you please upvote my answer and mark it as correct solution.